# Usuário postando e respondendo em seguida

Tags: debate

O usuário [Fábio Perez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/16015/f%C3%A1bio-perez) postou 3 perguntas:

1. [Verificar se um valor está presente em um array em Ruby](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50391/3635)
2. [Indentar todo código automaticamente no vim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50388/3635)
3. [Como fazer commit apenas em um pedaço de um arquivo no Git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50382/3635)

Todas ele respondeu logo em seguida. O problema não é só este. Eu não sei como ele postou uma resposta no mesmo segundo que perguntou (eu nem sabia que isto era possível).

Como proceder?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: [Respondi minha própria pergunta, fiz algo errado?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37/91)

Comment: Entendido :) Obrigado

Comment: Já agora @bfavaretto a pergunta do link não está traduzida.

Comment: @JorgeB. Avisei o Gabe e ele já corrigiu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não há problema algum em fazer isto como já demonstrado nos comentários e existe até um recurso na página da pergunta para responder junto com a pergunta, o que mostra como o mecanismo foi feito para isto.

Claro que se um usuário começar postar pares de perguntas e respostas seguidas precisa ser observado. É interessante ter perguntas e respostas de qualidade independente de quem postou cada uma delas. Inundar o *site* com perguntas pouco selecionadas pode começar se tornar um problema se feito em exagero, mas em geral isto não acontece e até agora o caso relatado nem chegou perto de demonstrar algum problema, pelo contrário.

Observar se há comportamentos abusivos, sim. Tomar ações só porque há postagens seguidas de pares de P&R, não.

Comment: E é por isto que eu perguntei antes de tomar qualquer ação, obrigado